# variable gets reset when typing in flutter textfield

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter mobile apps and have created my first one. I am learning about how they work. I found out today that when I type in a Textfield that is connected to controller the entire page seems to get reprocessed.

When this happens the variable that populates the value of a dropdownbutton gets nulled out. The variable name is _currentAgentState and when the page first builds everything works fine but when I type the first letter in any of the textfield widgets the page rebuilds and the variable is empty. I have followed the variable through the whole process in the debugger but I can't see where it is being changed. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
final agentsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('agents'));
final agencyRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('agency'));

class AgentProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'agent_profile_screen';
  final Agents agents;

  AgentProfileScreen([this.agents]);

  @override
  _AgentProfileScreenState createState() => _AgentProfileScreenState();
}

class _AgentProfileScreenState extends State<AgentProfileScreen> {
  final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final fNameController = TextEditingController();
  final lNameController = TextEditingController();
  final address1Controller = TextEditingController();
  final address2Controller = TextEditingController();
  final cityController = TextEditingController();
  final stateController = TextEditingController();
  final zipController = TextEditingController();
  final cellPhoneController = TextEditingController();
  final officePhoneController = TextEditingController();
  final agencyController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    fNameController.dispose();
    lNameController.dispose();
    address1Controller.dispose();
    address2Controller.dispose();
    cityController.dispose();
    stateController.dispose();
    zipController.dispose();
    cellPhoneController.dispose();
    officePhoneController.dispose();
    agencyController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool showSpinner = false;
  String email;
  String password;
  String fName;
  String lName;
  String address1;
  String address2;
  String city;
  String state;
  String zip;
  String cellPhone;
  String officePhone;
  String agency;

  String _currentAgentState = globals.currentAgentState;
  String _currentAgencyState;
  String _currentAgency;

  getCurrentAgentProfile() async {
        //String currentAgencyId = currentAgentProfile.data()["agencyId"];

    if (globals.newAgent == true) {
      final DocumentSnapshot currentAgencyProfile =
          await agencyRef.doc(globals.agencyId).get();

      emailController.text = null;
      fNameController.text = null;
      lNameController.text = null;
      address1Controller.text = currentAgencyProfile.data()['address1'];
      address2Controller.text = currentAgencyProfile.data()['address2'];
      cityController.text = currentAgencyProfile.data()['city'];
      //stateController.text = currentAgencyProfile.data()['state'];
      //globals.currentAgencyState = currentAgencyProfile.data()['state'];
      //_currentAgentState = currentAgencyProfile.data()['state'];
      //_currentAgencyState = currentAgencyProfile.data()['state'];
      zipController.text = currentAgencyProfile.data()['zipCode'].toString();
      cellPhoneController.text = currentAgencyProfile.data()['cellPhone'];
      officePhoneController.text = currentAgencyProfile.data()['officePhone'];
      agencyController.text = currentAgencyProfile.data()['name'];
      // Updates State
      new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        final agentProvider =
        Provider.of<AgentProvider>(context, listen: false);
        agentProvider.loadValues(Agents());
      });
    } else {
      final DocumentSnapshot currentAgentProfile =
          await agentsRef.doc(globals.currentAgentId).get();

      // existing record
      // Updates Controllers
      emailController.text = currentAgentProfile.data()["email"];
      fNameController.text = currentAgentProfile.data()['fName'];
      lNameController.text = currentAgentProfile.data()['lName'];
      address1Controller.text = currentAgentProfile.data()['address1'];
      address2Controller.text = currentAgentProfile.data()['address2'];
      cityController.text = currentAgentProfile.data()['city'];
      //stateController.text = currentAgentProfile.data()['state'];
      _currentAgentState = currentAgentProfile.data()['state'];
      if (currentAgentProfile.data()['state'] == "" || currentAgentProfile.data()['state'] == null) {
        _currentAgencyState = globals.currentAgentState;
      } else {
        _currentAgencyState = currentAgentProfile.data()['state'];
      };
      zipController.text = currentAgentProfile.data()['zipCode'].toString();
      cellPhoneController.text = currentAgentProfile.data()['cellPhone'];
      officePhoneController.text = currentAgentProfile.data()['officePhone'];
      agencyController.text = currentAgentProfile.data()['agency'];
      //globals.currentAgentId = currentAgentProfile.data()['agentId'];
      // Updates State
      new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        final agentProvider =
        Provider.of<AgentProvider>(context, listen: false);
        agentProvider.loadValues(widget.agents);
      });
    }

  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropDownState;

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getDropDownState() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = [];
    for (String state in globals.states) {
      items.add(new DropdownMenuItem(
          value: state,
          child: new Text(
            state,
          )));
    }
    return items;
  }

  void changedDropDownState(String selectedState) {
    setState(() {
      _currentAgentState = selectedState;
      globals.selectedAgentState = selectedState;
      globals.currentAgentState = selectedState;
    });
  }

  void changedDropDownAgency(String selectedAgency) {
    setState(() {
      _currentAgency = selectedAgency;
      globals.selectedAgency = selectedAgency;
      globals.currentAgencyName = selectedAgency;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentAgentProfile();
    if (globals.currentAgentState == "" || globals.currentAgentState == null) {
      _currentAgentState = globals.currentAgencyState;
    } else{
      _currentAgentState = globals.currentAgentState;
    };
    _currentAgency = globals.agencyId;
    _currentAgencyState = globals.currentAgencyState;
    super.initState();

    _dropDownState = getDropDownState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Get the stream of agents created in main.dart
    final agentProvider = Provider.of<AgentProvider>(context);
    final _firestoreService = FirestoreService();
    //String _chosenState = 'Select State';

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset('assets/images/Appbar_logo.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 56),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Agent Profile',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                // Email entry text field
                TextField(
                  controller: fNameController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    agentProvider.changefName(value);
                  },
                  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                      hintText: 'First Name', labelText: 'First Name'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: lNameController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    agentProvider.changelName(value);
                  },
                  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                      hintText: 'Last Name', labelText: 'Last Name'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                      stream: _db.collection('agency').snapshots(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.data == null) {
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return new DropdownButton<String>(
                            hint: new Text("Select Agency"),
                            value: _currentAgency,
                            onChanged: changedDropDownAgency,
                            items: snapshot.data.docs
                                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((document) {
                              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: document.id,
                                child: new Text(document.data()['name']),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          );
                        }
                      }),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: address1Controller,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    agentProvider.changeaddress1(value);
                  },
                  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                      hintText: 'Address 1', labelText: 'Address 1'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: address2Controller,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    agentProvider.changeaddress2(value);
                  },
                  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                      hintText: 'Address 2', labelText: 'Address 2'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: cityController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    agentProvider.changecity(value);
                  },
                  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                      hintText: 'City', labelText: 'City'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                DropdownButton(
                  value: _currentAgentState,
                  items: _dropDownState,
                  hint: Text('Choose State'),
                  onChanged: changedDropDownState,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: zipController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    agentProvider.changezipCode(value);
                  },
                  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                      hintText: 'Zip Code', labelText: 'Zip Code'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: cellPhoneController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    agentProvider.changecellPhone(value);
                  },
                  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                      hintText: 'Cell Phone', labelText: 'Cell Phone'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: officePhoneController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    agentProvider.changeofficePhone(value);
                  },
                  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                      hintText: 'Office Phone', labelText: 'Office Phone'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                RoundedButton(
                  title: 'Save',
                  colour: Colors.blueAccent,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      agentProvider.saveAgent();
                      globals.currentAgentName = fNameController.value.text + ' ' + lNameController.value.text;
                      globals.currentAgentState = _currentAgentState;
                      await _firestoreService.saveDeviceToken();
                      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => AgentDashboardScreen()));

                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } catch (e) {
                      // todo: add better error handling
                      print(e);
                    }
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),

                (widget != null)
                    ? RoundedButton(
                        title: 'Delete',
                        colour: Colors.red,
                        onPressed: () async {
                          setState(() {
                            showSpinner = true;
                          });
                          try {
                            agentProvider.deleteAgent(globals.currentUid);
                            globals.targetScreen = 2;
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                new MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => MainScreen()));
                            //Navigator.pushNamed(
                            //    context, AgentDashboardScreen.id);

                            setState(() {
                              showSpinner = false;
                            });
                          } catch (e) {
                            // todo: add better error handling
                            print(e);
                          }
                        },
                      )
                    : Container()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          setState(() {
            showSpinner = true;
          });
          try {
            agentProvider.saveAgent();
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => AgentDashboardScreen(),
              ),
            );
            setState(() {
              showSpinner = false;
            });
          } catch (e) {
            // todo: add better error handling
            print(e);
          }
        },
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.assignment_turned_in_outlined,
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found out today that when I type in a Textfield that is connected to controller the entire page seems to get reprocessed.

It is happening because you are listening to all the changes in `AgentProvider` and you are changing it when you are typing anything

> onChanged: (value) {
> agentProvider.changefName(value);
> },

If you dont want your widget to rebuild everytime `AgentProvider` changes. then instead of

> ```
> final agentProvider = Provider.of<AgentProvider>(context);
> ```

do this

> ```
> final agentProvider = Provider.of<AgentProvider>(context, listen: false);
> ```

// Edit

```
How do I keep this variable from being reset to an empty string?
```

To do this pass the `value` to the `controller` on every rebuild, else it will start from blank string.

Can be implemented like this :

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // Get the stream of agents created in main.dart
   final agentProvider = Provider.of<AgentProvider>(context);
   final _firestoreService = FirestoreService();
   //String _chosenState = 'Select State';

   // pass the value for each controller
   fNameController.text(fName); // fname is the value you want as 
                   // the initial value now, you can get it from 
                   // your provider or anywhere.

   ...
   ...
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I accept the page rebuilding but the first time it rebuilds the variable _currentAgentState is being set to "".  I have breakpoints at each line of code where the variable is used and the only breakpoint that stops during rebuild is at the DropdownButton for the "state". Why is this happening? How do I keep this variable from being reset to an empty string?

Comment: @LostTexan I have updated the answer, you can try that